# Save PDF from Word that are searchable, links to bookmarks works and high quality

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-office, bookmarks

I use Microsoft Office 365 Enterprise, and I would like to save a Word file as a PDF that is searchable and where the links to bookmarks work. I use these links for literature references and in the table of contents. When I print the file to PDF, the PDF is of high quality and searchable, but the links do not work. If I export it to PDF or save the file as a PDF, the links work, but the quality is poor, and it's not searchable. How can I save my file as a PDF with both good quality, searchable content, and working links?

Thank you in advance.